# What is wrong with this flood fill algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, flood-fill

https://www.kakaocode.com/tryouts/1353/intro

Given a picture array, the code should return the number of separated areas and size of a maximum area.

The color is represented as an integer (0 for white. white area doesn't count).

m and n are # of row and col each.

For example,

```
m = 6, n = 4 
1 1 1 0
1 2 2 0
1 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 3
0 0 0 3
```

should return `[4, 5]` because there are 4 separate areas and the largest area contains 5 ones.

Another example:

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1
```

this one should return `[2, 6]`

```
public int max = 0;
public int[] solution(int m, int n, int[][] picture) {
    // answer[0] = numberOfArea
    // answer[1] = maxSizeOfOneArea
    int[] answer = new int[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (picture[i][j] != 0){
                max = 0;
                floodFill(i, j, picture[i][j], picture);
                if (max > answer[1])   answer[1] = max;
                answer[0]++;
            }
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

public void floodFill(int i, int j, int num, int[][] picture){
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= picture.length || j >= picture[0].length || picture[i][j] != num)
        return;
    max++;
    picture[i][j] = 0;
    floodFill(i - 1, j, num, picture);
    floodFill(i + 1, j, num, picture);
    floodFill(i, j - 1, num, picture);
    floodFill(i, j + 1, num, picture);
}
```

I tried multiple test cases and it passed all, but it failed when I submitted.

What are some edge cases that I am missing?

Comment: It seems like the link that you've posted is behind a register-process. Can you explain the task a bit? And if it has pictures that might help understand the problem, could you add them here?

Comment: So sorry, I changed the link.

Comment: Do you know why it fails? Timeout? Wrong result?

Comment: Wrong result. you can try with your own code by going into the link (use chrome to translate). Also, you can add test cases but I couldn't find any cases that above code fails.

Comment: Have you run this yourself on some inputs to see what outputs you get, and then considered why you are getting those outputs?

Comment: It passes every input that I can think of. I am looking for an edge case... Because the website doesn't show which test case I failed.

Comment: Which testcases did you try exactly?

Comment: Any chance that you're getting stack overflow error? Did you try a 100x100 sample all filled with ones?

Comment: Yes, it was stack overflow. Thanks. Any improvement with this code? Should I use Stack instead of recursion?

Comment: Yes, a stack or queue (since the order is unimportant) should be fine.